# Manipulation of array

Tags: php, arrays

I've spent so much time on trying to figure out how to create a loop.This 
     is my array in php. I want to manipulate this array offsets from 0 to 1,1 to 2,2 to 3,3 to 4.

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => 2018-02-26 13:15
        [1] => 2018-02-26 13:30
        [2] => 2018-02-26 13:45
        [3] => 2018-02-26 14:00
        [4] => 2018-02-26 14:15
        [5] => 2018-02-26 14:30
        [6] => 2018-02-26 14:45
        [7] => 2018-02-26 15:00
        [8] => 2018-02-26 15:15
    )
```

I want to manipulate this array offsets from 0 to 1,1 to 2,2 to 3,3 to 4. 
I am trying to achieve below. Need help on this.I am new here so adding random test please ignore this

```
Array
    (
       [0] => Array
            (
                [start_datetime] => 2018-02-26 13:15
                [end_datetime] => 2018-02-26 13:30
                [break] => 0
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [start_datetime] => 2018-02-26 13:30
                [end_datetime] => 2018-02-26 13:45
                [break] => 0
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [start_datetime] => 2018-02-26 13:45
                [end_datetime] => 2018-02-26 14:00
                [break] => 0
            )
        [3] => Array
            (
                [start_datetime] => 2018-02-26 14:00
                [end_datetime] => 2018-02-26 14:15
                [break] => 0
            )
         .....
    )
```

Comment: no idea how the top array relates to the bottom array

Comment: "i m new here so adding random test please ignore this": If your question is good, StackOverflow would let you ask a question immediately. Otherwise (you have to add random text or code) you're probably doing something wrong. If you disagree you can ask on [meta] (need 15 reputation).

Comment: @rtfm i changed array

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for` or `foreach` to iterate over the index positions of the dates and increment the current index by one to retrieve the desired `end_date`. Repeat the iteration until the end of the array or the `end_date` is not defined.

```
$data = [
    0 => '2018-02-26 13:15',
    1 => '2018-02-26 13:30',
    2 => '2018-02-26 13:45',
    3 => '2018-02-26 14:00',
    4 => '2018-02-26 14:15',
    5 => '2018-02-26 14:30',
    6 => '2018-02-26 14:45',
    7 => '2018-02-26 15:00',
    8 => '2018-02-26 15:15'
];
$store = [];
$l = count($data)-1;
for($i = 0; $i<$l; $i++) {
    if(!isset($data[$i+1])){
        continue;
    }
    $store[] = [
        'start_date' => $data[$i],
        'end_date' => $data[$i+1],
        'break' => 0
    ];
}
var_dump($store);
```

Result: https://3v4l.org/5sSjs

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["start_date"]=>
    string(16) "2018-02-26 13:15"
    ["end_date"]=>
    string(16) "2018-02-26 13:30"
    ["break"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["start_date"]=>
    string(16) "2018-02-26 13:30"
    ["end_date"]=>
    string(16) "2018-02-26 13:45"
    ["break"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["start_date"]=>
    string(16) "2018-02-26 13:45"
    ["end_date"]=>
    string(16) "2018-02-26 14:00"
    ["break"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["start_date"]=>
    string(16) "2018-02-26 14:00"
    ["end_date"]=>
    string(16) "2018-02-26 14:15"
    ["break"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  [4]=>
  array(3) {
    ["start_date"]=>
    string(16) "2018-02-26 14:15"
    ["end_date"]=>
    string(16) "2018-02-26 14:30"
    ["break"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  [5]=>
  array(3) {
    ["start_date"]=>
    string(16) "2018-02-26 14:30"
    ["end_date"]=>
    string(16) "2018-02-26 14:45"
    ["break"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  [6]=>
  array(3) {
    ["start_date"]=>
    string(16) "2018-02-26 14:45"
    ["end_date"]=>
    string(16) "2018-02-26 15:00"
    ["break"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  [7]=>
  array(3) {
    ["start_date"]=>
    string(16) "2018-02-26 15:00"
    ["end_date"]=>
    string(16) "2018-02-26 15:15"
    ["break"]=>
    int(0)
  }
}
```

If you need to validate the date position, let me know and I will demonstrate a validation based method to populate the array.

Answer (score 0):

fyrye and i had the same approach, i just prefer `foreach()`

```
<?php

   $a=array (
        '0'=>'2018-02-26 13:15',
        '1'=>'2018-02-26 13:30',
        '2'=>'2018-02-26 13:45',
        '3'=>'2018-02-26 14:00',
        '4'=>'2018-02-26 14:15',
        '5'=>'2018-02-26 14:30',
        '6'=>'2018-02-26 14:45',
        '7'=>'2018-02-26 15:00',
        '8'=>'2018-02-26 15:15'
    );

    $new=array();

    foreach ($a as $k=>$each){ //loop each
    $new[$k]['start_datetime']=  $a[$k]; // the current value in the array
    $new[$k]['end_datetime'] = $a[$k+1];//the next value in the array 
    $new[$k]['break'] = 0;

    }

print_r($new);
```

Comment: I actually prefer `foreach` as well :) Keep in mind this will cause `Notice: Undefined offset: 9` for the last item.

Comment: hard to know if 8 without an end_datetime is wanted. So i wasn't sure if i should exclude the creation of 8 altogether or leave the creation of 8 and stop the notice - so in the end decided to do neither @fyrye